# How to check the number of requests being served by server

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ssh, dedicated-server, command

Can any one help with the command to check the number of requests being served by apache web server.

I know some commands to test the load of server, like **top** command to check the load on server and **free -m** command to check the RAM memory space on server.

I have SSH access to my server.

Answer (score 2):

There is a utility called [apachetop](http://linux.die.net/man/1/apachetop) that is available for a variety of Linux distros that will monitor your logs in real time and provide this information.

You may also find that [mod_status](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_status.html) will provide the information that you want.

Comment: I am new to handle servers, can you guide me how to use the commands you advice to use.
I tried using **apachetop** and **mod_status** but not working.
can you provide me example of commands to use.
thanks :)

Comment: when i fired the command it says something like this

**-bash: apachetop: command not found**

Comment: @JigarSavla: which Linux distro are you using ?

Comment: @lain- well I use amazon ec2

Answer (score 1):

Iain's suggestion is good for monitoring instantaneous information.  `Munin` will grab status information every 5 minutes and give you graphical results.

Your access logs can provide a wealth of information.  Tools that summarize the data such as `awstats` can generate useful information.

Answer (score 0):

Configure and interpret [**mod_status**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_status.html)

It offers all you could need to understand your servers' performance and behaviour.